Firefox: printing preview is wrong when coming from landscape to fixed portrait orientation
I want to have a printing page which is fixed to portrait orientation.
I'm using the following css for it:
@media print {
    @page {
        size: portrait;
    }
}

But if I print any other page in orientation 'landscape' in Firefox at first and then try to print my page (which is fixed in portrait mode), the preview screen is kind of broken.

Only when I change one of the options (for example pages: all to pages: current), then the preview updates and is correct again.

At first I thought it must by the fault of the FF on my system. I installed the current version 126.0.1 and tested it on another PC, but the initial preview is still wrong. I have tested it on Windows.
Steps to reproduce it:

Print any page in landscape orientation
Open the example below in FF
Print
Printing preview should look like the image above

Here is my example page where you can reproduce the behavior.
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    @media print {
        @page {
            size: portrait;
        }
    }
    
    .outer {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .outer > * {
        width: 49%;
        height: 49%;
        display: inline-flex;
        border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>c</div>
        <div>d</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

